# How do I find the "radius" of a cuboid along a given axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let's say I have a cuboid, which has the half extents $e_c = (e_{cx}, e_{cy}, e_{cz})$ (each component in that vector is half the length of four edges on a cuboid. This means that, for example, along $(0, 1, 0)$, with not rotation applied to the cuboid, it would have a half extent or "radius" along that axis of $e_{cy}$

Now bring in rotation to the cuboid. The cuboid's orientation is expressed as a quaternion $o$ and I get to pick an arbitrary axis with direction $a$. How do I find out the half-extent or "radius" or the orientated cuboid along that axis?